# Is it possible to send parameters to ValidationMessages_en_US.properties ?? How?

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

I have ValidationMessages_en_US.properties as below

```
requiredFirstName=First name is required
requiredLastName=Last name is required
requiredEmailAddress=Email Address is required
...
...
```

What I would like to do is parameterize the field name in this. So something like this

```
    requiredField={field} is required
```

So that there will be only one message and I can pass in the field name. I am using this in bean validations in the jsf environment.
This is where I want to use the values:

```
public class SomeBean implements Serializable
{
        @NotNull(message="{requiredFirstName}" )
        private String firstName;
        ......
        .....
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this with the current Bean Validation specification or reference implementation (Hibernate Validator). You can interpolate the validated value and the constraint parameters and with Validator 5.1 you will also be able to add custom variables via HibernateConstraintValidatorContext (see also https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-701). However, that does not help you yet to identify your fields and set the right 'field' value.